# Java getNetworkPrefixLength() always -1 on WLAN Stick

Tags: java, network-programming

I want to build a server, that is discoverable via Wifi inside a network. Therefore the server shall send UDP datagrams, to publish its existence.

On my PC I have got a WLAN stick. Reading out information with methods of a Java NetworkInterface and InterfaceAddress gives me the following information:

```
300Mbps Wireless USB Adapter
interface InetAddress: /192.168.43.16
interface address string in textual presentation: 192.168.43.16
network prefix length: -1
broadcast InetAddress: /96.113.104.12
broadcastAddress: 96.113.104.12

300Mbps Wireless USB Adapter
interface InetAddress: /192.168.43.16
interface address string in textual presentation: 192.168.43.16
network prefix length: -1
broadcast InetAddress: /0.0.0.0
broadcastAddress: 0.0.0.0
Exception in socket discovery beacon send thread.
```

Why am I getting multiple broadcast addresses for the same InetAddress?

Using **ipconfig /all** on my Windows PC tells me, my subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. So usually the network prefix length should be 24, or?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found an answer to that problem, posted on [this blog of Christian Rieck](http://www.christian-rieck.com/2014/02/08/java-interfaceaddress-getbroadcast-fehlerhaft/).

It says, that it is a bug inside the java source code. This bug got fixed with Java 8. So simply using Java 8 solved the problem for me.